# Is there a way to use as an optional field a json array value inside the payload? Karate DSL

Tags: karate

I'm starting to use Karate DSL for API testing. I've used before to do some basic tests.
I'm kind of mixing a dynamic data driven test, so I've read the documentacion and usages for this. I'm using the standalone jar file. Now, the problem is that I'm trying to use a json file as shown below:

```
[
  {
    "name": null,
    "type": "informational",
    "description": "Poseidon was one of the Twelve Olympians in ancient Greek religion and myth, god of the sea, storms.",
    "tags": null,
    "myAuth": null
  },
  {
    "name": "RegressionTestKarate-dsfdgfdgdfsgfdgsfdgfdsgfdsgsdfg",
    "type": "transactional",
    "description": null,
    "tags": ["regression", "poseidon", "suite", "test"],
    "myAuth": null
  }
]
```

And in my *.feature, I'm using the data to send a request like this:

```
* def myJson = { name: "##(name)", type: '##(type)', description: '##(description)', tags: '##(tags)' }    
Given url poseidonHostUrl
    And path "v1/projects"
      And request myJson
      When method post
      Then assert responseStatus == 400 || responseStatus == 401 || responseStatus == 403
```

So, when I run my script, the replacement for the tags array when is not null is not as expected. It literally takes the following value: `[...] "tags": "##(tags)"`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the above example shows your tags data is an array or null so you should try this as

```
* def myJson = { name: '##(name)', type: '##(type)', description: '##(description)', tags: '##[] #string' }    
Given url poseidonHostUrl
And path "v1/projects"
And request myJson
When method post
Then assert responseStatus == 400 || responseStatus == 401 || responseStatus == 403
```

Comment: Sorry, I've tried with the advised option, but still having the same issue. It didn't do the replacement for the array.

Comment: @Ricardgo please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue